# The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily Magento 2

Tags: authentication, magento, server, debian, magento2

From today when I try to enter the BO of the site it gives me this error:

```
The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later.
```

I have already tried to run this command from ssh:

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock ADMINUSERNAME
```

and I also changed the columns in the `admin_user` table:

```
is_active = 1
failures_num = 0
first_failure = NULL
lock_expires = NULL
```

and tried to reset my password and to make another admin account, but there is the same error, but it keeps getting that error. How can I solve?

EDIT

I've noticed that this problem shows up on the other sites I have on that server, so I think it's more of a server problem than magento.
The sites are on Debian 9.13 with plesk.

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs due to Magento 2’s security system. Magento 2 will temporarily disable accounts that **do not meet its password complexity requirements.**

By default, in Magento 2, the password that meets security requirements must consist of:

- Uppercase letters
- Lowercase letters
- Numeric
- Special characters
- Minimum of 8 characters

The following are the solutions to this issue. Try any of them to see if it works for you.

**Solution 1:** Unlock the Account

Magento 2 sometimes locks an account for security purposes. In this case, you can unlock it by going to your Magento 2 root folder in the command or terminal and run the below command:

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock <username>

Example: php bin/magento admin:user:unlock admin
```

**Solution2:**

Go to [localhost/phpmyadmin/](http://localhost/phpmyadmin/) on your browser and select your Magento 2 database.

After that use this syntax to change Magento 2 password using the Mysql command.

```
SET @salt = MD5(UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
UPDATE admin_user SET `password` = CONCAT(SHA2(CONCAT(@salt, 'NewP@ssword'), 256), ':', @salt, ':1') WHERE username = 'adminusername';
```

Replace:

- `NewP@ssword` with your desired password (must meet Magento 2 security requirement).
- `adminusername` with your admin account username.

**Example:**

```
SET @salt = MD5(UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
UPDATE admin_user SET `password` = CONCAT(SHA2(CONCAT(@salt, 'Admin@123456'), 256), ':', @salt, ':1') WHERE username = 'admin';
```

After running the command above, your admin account will be updated with the new password you set in `CONCAT(SHA2(CONCAT(@salt, 'NewP@ssword'), 256)`

Now you can login to your account normally.

**Solution 3: Create a New Admin Account**

If none of the above solutions work, create a new admin account. Run the command below via SSH

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="username" --admin-password="mypassword" --admin-email="youremail@mail.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin"

php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="Admin@123456" --admin-email="youremail@mail.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin"
```

Cheers !! :)

**Solution 4: Perform the following steps**

- Remove semicolon from the beginning of the line ;extension=sodium from php.ini which enables it.
- Copy C:\xampp\php\libsodium.dll to C:\xampp\apache\bin\
- Restart Apache means stop and start Apache.

After all that please run the following command in SSH

Please run following query:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento clear:cache
```

That’s it.

Thank You !!

Comment: As written in the post, I have already tried all these solutions, but none of them work. Also this problem shows up on the other sites I have on that server too, so I think it's more of a server problem rather than magento

Comment: So, you can go with Solution 3: Create a New Admin Account it's better.

Comment: I already did, but it gives the same error

Comment: Can you provide me access so we can check from my end? if Possible? @Gabbodrummer

Comment: you may want to use single quote for --admin-password='Admin@123456' otherwise if you put a weird char it may be interpreted by the shell, like the dollar. and the password set will not be what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Which is the server using? Apache

If yes then check for the Sodium extension is enabled or not in the php.ini file

Sometimes it causes issues while admin login.

Comment: I have Sodium active with version 10.11, do I have to deactivate it?

Comment: no it needs to be activated, since you have done everything I guess, please try to change the password from database use this query - SET @salt = MD5(UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
UPDATE admin_user SET `password` = CONCAT(SHA2(CONCAT(@salt, 'NewP@ssword'), 256), ':', @salt, ':1') WHERE username = 'adminusername';

Comment: I already did, but it gives the same error

Comment: Ask Server support then

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue with Magento 2.4.6.

**Steps**

1. Created an admin user.
2. Go to the admin login screen, Tried to log in with the new username and password, but it was throwing "The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily"

**The solution worked for me**

I have set a long expiration date for the user. The reason why I set this when I create the user Magento automatically set the expiration date to passed time on the same date, which I wasn't aware.

And Magento forcefully disables the user if he is passed the expiry date.

`vendor/magento/module-security/Observer/AdminUserAuthenticateBefore.php`

The second line modifies the user whenever you tried with an expired user.

```
if ($user->getId() && $this->userExpirationManager->isUserExpired($user->getId())) {
       $this->userExpirationManager->deactivateExpiredUsersById([$user->getId()]);
         throw new AuthenticationException(
             __(
             'The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. '
                    . 'Please wait and try again later.'
                )
            );
        }
```

Look at this table for more details `admin_user_expiration`. For me, there was a record associated with the user I created.

Changing to a future date solved me, also you can delete this entry from the database.

I know this is not the solution to the underlying problem, but this helps to alleviate some pain when dealing this with in the production systems.